# WP calendar summary attribute validation error

Tags: validation, calendar

When the calendar widget is activated in the sidebar, it generates the following validation error (W3C markup validation):

> The summary attribute is obsolete. Consider describing the structure
>   of the table in a caption element or in a figure element containing
>   the table; or, simplify the structure of the table so that no
>   description is needed.

```
…alendar</h3><div id="calendar_wrap"><table id="wp-calendar"
 summary="Calendar">
```

How can I rectify this without messing with any core file?

Working with WP3.1.4, twentyten theme.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update to 3.2.2. The summary attribute has been removed. See line 1149 \wp-includes\general-template.php

WP v3.1.4:

```
$calendar_output = '<table id="wp-calendar" summary="' . esc_attr__('Calendar') . '">
```

WP v3.2.2:

```
$calendar_output = '<table id="wp-calendar">
```

Alternatives... To modify the output of the widget, you can duplicate it and rename it. When I did that, I also needed to duplicate the get_calendar() function and adjust the calls to apply_filters() and the caching functions. It was worth the work, because I wanted complete control of the calendar widget's output.

Another approach is to use the get_calendar filter and modify the output using str_replace, simple xml, regex, etc. Here's a solution using str_replace() (add this code to functions.php):

```
add_filter( 'get_calendar', 'customize_calendar_output' );
function customize_calendar_output( $calendar_output ) {
    $calendar_output = str_replace( '<table id="wp-calendar" summary="' . esc_attr__('Calendar') . '">', '<table id="wp-calendar">', $calendar_output );
    return $calendar_output;
}
```

Comment: thanks for time and help. I prefer the Alternatives you mentioned, but I don get it. can you peovide more info please. thanks.

Comment: 10 continuing with my above comment, how can I filter $calendar_output = '<table id="wp-calendar" summary="' . esc_attr__('Calendar') . '">  to $calendar_output = '<table id="wp-calendar">

Comment: Updating WP is the best way for sure, but I've updated my answer with a solution using the get_calender filter.

Comment: 10, sorry I spoke to soon, the filter did not resolve the error

Comment: I tested it before I posted the code. It worked. Please give more details or show your code. If you do:

add_filter( 'calendar_output', 'customize_calendar_output' );
function customize_calendar_output( $calendar_output ) {
    $calendar_output = '<h1>TEST TEST TEST</h1>' . $calendar_output;
    return $calendar_output;
}

does the h1 show up?

Comment: See http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/11554 for details on the patch that fixed your problem. If you're really concerned about having valid code (especially on a draft spec), you shouldn't be running on an old version of WP.

Comment: 10, Thanks for your patent and time. I placed your code in my themes functions.php, and I get thexactly the same validation error as I indicated in my initial question. No change. I dont' understand about h1, but when view the source of my page in the browser I see this: <li id="calendar-3" class="widget-container widget_calendar"><h3 class="widget-title">Calendar</h3><div id="calendar_wrap"><table id="wp-calendar" summary="Calendar">

Comment: Try deleting the widget, then re-adding it. There could be something going on with caching (of course make sure any caching plugins are disabled too, if you use them).

Comment: I tried, and no change. just for testing purposes, when I replace the line #1149 in general-template.php with $calendar_output = '<table id="wp-calendar"> it works.

Comment: Whew, OK, I was about to throw in the towel. I fixed my answer.  Note that the name of the filter we're hooking onto is "get_calendar".  Give that code in the answer another go.  I fixed this in my testing code last night, and didn't correct it in the answer.  Sorry about that!

Comment: Woo-hoo! No prob t-p, glad we finally got it!